# HTMLPurifier not working on live system

Tags: php, zend-framework2, htmlpurifier

I have downloaded and installed HTMLPurifier with zendframework2, I have tested it very well and it works very fine. only when i try it on the live system, it doesn't work. there are even no errors nor wornings. what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake. Zend framework is doing its own escaping to the user input. And i have in turn to decode it into UTF-8 using this function.

```
 html_entity_decode($this->getRequest ()->getPost ('task_masterdata_description'),
 ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'),
```